# Copy value-only cells in multiple worksheet columns and paste into one column

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple spreadsheets that I need to copy column starting at "S4", on a specifically named worksheet, and I need only the cells in that column (starting at S4 and everything below it) that contain data.

I need to copy that data and paste it into my "main" spreadsheet starting at A2 on a specific worksheet.  I can do this with one spreadsheet, but the problem I'm running into I need VBA to find the last cell in column A that has a value and start pasting new data into the cell below it, etc... Otherwise, when it's looking at the other spreadsheets, it's just overwriting the data in my main spreadsheet.

You'll notice the specified range of S4:S2000 - its purpose was for a single spreadsheet, which worked fine because I never had data past 2000, but I really just need it looking for cell values and grabbing those.

This is the chunk of code where I'm having the trouble.  I want it to search starting at A2 (skipping the column header), look for the last cell that has a value and paste cells with values starting at S4 on the other worksheet.

```
On Error Resume Next
        Set wbkCS = Workbooks.Open(strCutSheetFile(i))
        On Error GoTo 0
    If Not wbkCS Is Nothing Then
        With wbkVer.Sheets("Cutsheets")
             .Range(.Cells(2,1)).End(xlUp).Row = wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000").Value
```

I had to tweak yours a little because I'm working with protected files, but this worked:

```
Set copyRng1 = Worksheets("Cutsheets").Range("A2")

If copyRng1 = "" Then
        wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000").Locked = False
        wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000").Copy Destination:=wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets").Range("A2")
    Else
        wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000").Copy Destination:=wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets").Range("A" & wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1)

    End If
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to copy S4:S2000 from a bunch of worksheets in the same workbook and paste into a single column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that may push you in the right direction...

Suppose I want to aggregate my data in `Sheet1` using data from `S4:S2000` in all other worksheets in the workbook.

```
Sub CopyAndStack()
    Dim wkShtIndex As Integer, copyRng As Range

    Set copyRng = Worksheets(1).Range("A2")

    For wkShtIndex = 2 To Worksheets.Count
        If copyRng = "" Then
            Worksheets(wkShtIndex).Range("S4:S2000").Copy Destination:=copyRng
        Else
            Worksheets(wkShtIndex).Range("S4:S2000").Copy Destination:=Range("A" & copyRng.End(xlDown).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next wkShtIndex
End Sub
```

I check if `A2` is empty and if so I paste the first lot of data.

If `A2` is not empty I get the next empty cell in column A and paste it there.

Comment: Thank you! One question/issue: There might be times when there are empty cells between values in the S4-S2000 range. So, when pasting would this find an empty pasted cell that could be within already pasted values and overwrite? --Or does this copy only the cells with values? How would I check ...maybe A2 to A2000 for the last empty cell? Thanks!

Comment: Ok. In which case change `copyRng.End(xlDown).Row + 1` to `Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1`. This will avoid the issue you are describing.

Comment: I'm almost there! :)   The first part works, but when it gets to the 2nd piece of looking for the open cell to paste the data (else statement), it doesn't do anything and seems to just skip right by it?  I can see the logic is working with the if/then statement for "copyRng". Thoughts?  No error, just doesn't do it.  I'll post my edited code above.

Comment: I believe this might be an issue with locked cells and will confirm.

Comment: Ok. Let me know if you still have an issue and I'll try to sort it for you.

Comment: Got it working and posted the final code above. I needed to change the else statement a little to get it working.  Thank you!

Comment: Excellent news. There's always a way with Excel VBA!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can get exactly the rows that are populated in S:

```
Dim StrRange As String

. . .

'Get range
strRange = "S4:S" & Worksheets(wkShtIndex).UsedRange.Columns("S:S").Rows.Count  
'Do something with range
Worksheets(wkShtIndex).Range(strRange)
```